# Munin - Netstat Graph

Tags: centos, munin, graph

I've installed Munin on a couple of our servers (CentOS) so I'll have some way to monitor what is going on.

In one server it looks good with proper value-ranges:

[image: netstat1]

In others it looks like this:

[image: netstat2]

Has anyone run into this ? 
I can't find any info on such an issue?

Thanks,
Alon

Comment: Could you telnet to one bad server and one good server on port 4949 (from the central munin server), do a `config NAME-OF-PLUGIN`, and edit the results in each case into your question above?

Comment: Cool I see that the one working well has this: graph_args -l 0 --base 1000 while the one that isn't working has this: graph_args --base 1000 --logarithmic

Comment: Will try to see how I can configure this

Comment: Maybe a bit of an awkward place to change this, either way I updated it directly in the plugin code in /etc/munin/plugins/netstat and it fixed it. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Glad we fixed it.  I've written my comment up as an answer, in the hope that you will see fit to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you telnet to a bad server and a good server on port 4949, from the central munin server, and do a `config NAME-OF-PLUGIN`, I expect that you'll see that the bad plugin passes `graph_args --logarithmic` and the good one doesn't.  Fix the one that does, and you should stop getting log-lin graphs.